# A conexão subjacente estava fechada: A conexão foi fechada de modo inesperado

Tags: c#, webforms, post

Estou com projeto em WebForm, e estou passando um array para um método que vai fazer um post para uma URL especifica. Porém, depois que executo o projeto e mando o array para o método, ele quebra com o erro informado no título.

```
   private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://MINHAURL.COM/QUE-RECEBE-O-POST/");
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.Accept = "application/json";
        request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.KeepAlive = false;

        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string data = "browser=Win7x64-C1|Chrome32|1024x768&url=https://MINHAURL.COM/QUE-RECEBE-O-POST/";

            streamWriter.Write(data);
        }

        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         var user = new Usuarios();
        var lista = new string[]
        {
            user.name,
            user.dt_nascimento,
            user.cidade
        };

        webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(lista, null);
    }
```

Comment: Não sei exatamente qual é o problema. Mas começa errado por usar um método para notificar evento como método normal de execução. Dá manda coisas sem sentido para ele. E nem usa o que foi mandado, então mandar para que? Provavelmente o site que está querendo acessar exige algo que não está sendo passado, como SSL, por exemplo, ou mesmo nem seja um local acessível. Se o endereço for `https://wwww.minhaurl.com/` realmente o erro é consistente. Fora isto, teria que passar mais informações para conseguir responder.

Comment: @bigown existe uma url especifica que vai receber esse post. Essa "minhaurl" que passei, é apenas o exemplo. Tanto, quanto o array que passo abaixo, ambos são fictícios.